# How to create a Regex function that matches image alt text for two keys

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match two values from an images alt text. There will be other text inside these alt as well that can be ignored.
The property will be either size or crop.

The alt tags would look like:

- alt="size: 16 crop: mid crop"
- alt="size: 16 crop: close crop"
- alt="size: 16 crop: full body"
- alt="size: 8 crop: mid crop"
- alt="size: 8 crop: close crop"
- alt="size: 8 crop: full body"
- alt="size: 0 crop: mid crop"
- alt="size: 0 crop: close crop"
- alt="size: 0 crop: full body"

For size I'm trying to get "0" or "8" or "16"
For crop I'm trying to get "full body" or "mid crop" or "close crop"

is this possible?

```
function getImageProperty(image, property) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`${property}: (.+)[]]`, 'g');
  const matches = image.altText.match(regex);

  return matches && matches[1];
}

     /**
     * Returns a matching product image for provided size and crop.
     */
    const getMatchingImage = (images: size, crop) => {
      return images.find(
        (image) =>
          getImageProperty(image, size) && getImageProperty(image, crop),
      );
    };
```

Comment: Maybe replace `.+` with `.*?`?

Comment: What would be an example of the params you would be passing into your `getImageProperty` method?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that doesn't work either.

Comment: @dalelandry I added the next function that calls on the 1st one, does that help?

Comment: Are you looking to match a given size and `crop` property with some images that are in a DOM list or some kind of object?

Comment: I'm looking though a list of product images which is an array of objects to randomly display 3 images for each card based on the atl text. the object would look  like {url: "/", altText: "size: 16 crop: mid crop", width: 50, height: 50 ...}

Comment: Also Dustin I think it is good to point out the following: The alt attribute holds a text description of the image, which isn't mandatory but is incredibly useful for ***accessibility — screen readers*** read this description out to their users so they know what the image means. Alt text is also displayed on the page if the image can't be loaded for some reason: for example, network errors, content blocking, or linkrot. Personally, I would suggest you use data-set attributes in place of using an alt tag and use the alt tag for explanation of what your image is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regex, which will match everything after the property name and up to either end-of-string or the next property name:

```
\bsize: (.*?)(?=\s\w+:|$)
```

`size` would be replaced with whichever property name was appropriate.

```js
images = document.querySelectorAll('img')

properties = ['size', 'crop']

function getImageProperty(image, property) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${property}: (.*?)(?=\\s\\w+:|$)`)
  const matches = image.getAttribute('alt').match(regex)
  return matches && matches[1]
}

[...images].forEach((img, i) =>
  properties.forEach(prop => console.log(`image ${i} ${prop} = ${getImageProperty(img,prop)}`))
)
```

```html
<img alt="size: 16 crop: mid crop" />
<img alt="crop: close crop size: 16" />
<img alt="size: 16 crop: full body" />
<img alt="crop: mid crop size: 8" />
<img alt="size: 8 crop: close crop" />
<img alt="size: 8 crop: full body" />
<img alt="size: 0 crop: mid crop" />
<img alt="size: 0 crop: close crop" />
<img alt="crop: full body size: 0" />
```

Comment: @dustin did you try this?

Comment: Yeah, I ran into a the similar problem where matches[1] is undefined. Feel free to look at my profile for a previous question which shows the entire code I'm running. I was just trying to break it down and find the root of the issues which I think is the regex. Thanks

Comment: @dustin that's because you're using the `g` flag (you'll notice I don't use it in my code). When you use the `g` flag, you get an array of all the matches in the text, *not* an array with all the capture groups (see the [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#return_value)). Since you only have one match in the text, this means `matches[1]` will be undefined. Remove the `g` flag and it should work fine (as my code snippet does)

Comment: Note in my code just for demo purposes I've used `getAttribute('alt')`, you would of course still use `altText` there.

Comment: You're right, it was due to the `g` flag. I'll mark yours as correct since it's the way I went. However you might to declare the variables? `const regex =` and `const matches =`

Comment: @dustin oops. Too much going back and forth between JS/python/PHP... I've fixed that now. I'm glad this solved your problem. It did occur to me (after reading your last comment to the question) though that - if you can modify the `image` objects, you should just parse the `altText` into properties on the object; then you won't need to call this function every time you want to look up a property value.

Answer (score 2):

The format `"size: 16 crop: mid crop"` is non-determanistic because there is no separator after the size value, such as `"size: 16, crop: mid crop"` would.

You can use a negative lookahead to work around this:

```
  const regex = new RegExp(`${property}: (\\w+( (?!crop:)\\w+)?)`);
```

If you have control over the alt text and chose `,` as a separator you can change the regex to:

```
  const regex = new RegExp(`${property}: ([^,"]+)`);
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is a working example with what appears to be your `image` object format:

```js
function getImageProperty(image, property) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`${property}: ([^,"]+)`);
  const matches = image.altText.match(regex);
  return matches && matches[1];
}

[
  'size: 16, crop: mid crop',
  'size: 16, crop: close crop',
  'size: 16, crop: full body',
  'size: 8, crop: mid crop',
  'size: 8, crop: close crop',
  'size: 8, crop: full body',
  'size: 0, crop: mid crop',
  'size: 0, crop: close crop',
  'size: 0, crop: full body'
].forEach(str => {
  let image = { altText: str };
  console.log(image.altText
    + '\n=> size: ' + getImageProperty(image, 'size')
    + '\n=> crop: ' + getImageProperty(image, 'crop')
  );
});
```

Comment: I tried both because I do have control over the alt text. However, I wasn't able to get either to work.  matches return the size, but matches[1] returns undefined

Comment: @dustin: I added code with your examples

Answer (score 2):

An alternate to using regex would be to use `split()` and get the comparative values out of the *altText* string.

`altText.split(':')[1].split(' ')[1].trim()` will return the **size**

`altText.split(':')[2].split(' ').join(' ').trim()` will return the **cropped** value

In the snipit, I pass in an object of images, a target size and a cropped property into the getMatchingItem method. this will extract the size and cropped value and return an array of images that match. In the example I match the cropped value and size to find objects with the same values and display them on the page.

Let me know if this isn't what you're looking for.

```js
function getMatchingImage(list, size, property) {
  // set the output to null or some string initially
  let output = [];
  // iterate over the image elements
  list.forEach((img, index) => {
    // get the alt attribubtes string
    const alt = img.altText
    // use split for each targeted value size and crop at the colon
    // then take the second indexed string and split again 
    // at the second spaces index and trim any white space JIC
    let altSize = alt.split(':')[1].split(' ')[1].trim()
    // repeat split and get the third indexed string and again split using spaces 
    // join the resulting remaining indexed strings and trim them
    let altCrop = alt.split(':')[2].split(' ').join(' ').trim()
    // conditional to check the image elements size and crop
    // matches the passed values size and property
    // if there is a match we push the value into an output array
    altSize === size && altCrop === property ? output.push(list[index]) : null
  })
  console.log(output)
  // return an array of values
  return output
}

// a method to display any matching images found
const displayFoundImage = (imgObjSrc) => {
  // iterate over list of found images
  imgObjSrc.map(imgObj => {
    // search through database images 
    return databaseImages.map(img => {
      // is there a match?
      if (img.src === imgObj.src) {
        // create an image element
        let imageEl = document.createElement('img')
        // set image elements src and alt attribute values
        imageEl.src = imgObj.src
        imageEl.alt = img.altText
        // append body and add image
        document.body.appendChild(imageEl)
        console.log(imageEl)
      }
    })
  })

}

const databaseImages = [{
    src: "https://picsum.photos/100/100",
    altText: "size: 16 crop: mid crop"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/101/100",
    altText: "size: 16 crop: close crop"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/102/100",
    altText: "size: 16 crop: full body"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/103/100",
    altText: "size: 8 crop: mid crop"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/104/100",
    altText: "size: 8 crop: close crop"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/105/100",
    altText: "size: 8 crop: full body"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/106/100",
    altText: "size: 8 crop: mid crop"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/107/100",
    altText: "size: 8 crop: close crop"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/108/100",
    altText: "size: 8 crop: full body"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/109/100",
    altText: "size: 0 crop: mid crop"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/110/100",
    altText: "size: 0 crop: close crop"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/111/100",
    altText: "size: 0 crop: full body"
  }
]

const foundImage = getMatchingImage(databaseImages, '8', 'full body')

displayFoundImage(foundImage)
```